# Yellow vs yellow-green wires

Tags: wiring

I have a simple light switch with yellow wire (load side) and a blue wire (line side).  I am installing a smart switch and the ground wire is yellow-green. I am assuming that yellow and yellow-green wires are used for these different functions?

Comment: The bottom line is that colors don't necessarily have to mean anything.  You should ALWAYS read the instructions and know what wires are what with respect to what you are connecting to.  Making assumptions can cause damage and injury.

Comment: Do not assume, or become the first three letters.  In North America ground is bare, green, or green with yellow.  Load/line side is usually hot/live and connecting to ground is usually bad.

Comment: Bare, green and yellow-w/-green-stripe are nearly world standard ground colors.  Yellow-green is ground  in most of the rest of the world, and it's in NA colors because we *harmonized* ground colors with the rest of the world.  Yellow is a completely different color and is HOT.

Comment: @harper why not make that an answer?

Comment: Usually green-with-yellow-stripe, or stripes, plural,  IME. *i.e.* not Yellow-with-green-stripe(s), though the green would in either case make me think it should be ground. Just never seen yellow-with-green-stripe(s), plenty of green-with-yellow-stripe(s).

Comment: What country are you in? That can determine wire colors in some cases.

Comment: What make and model of switch are you trying to install? Also, can you post a photo of the inside of the box in question please?

Answer (score 3):

### You have metal conduit.

That means all the stuff you read/watch on the Internet about home wiring does not apply to you.  Your colors are not black/white/sometimes red.  They are a variety of colors, as follows:

- Safety ground: Green, **yellow w/ green stripe**, or bare.
- Neutral: White or gray
- Hot: All else, e.g. black brown red orange **yellow** pink blue purple

The reason green/yellow stripe is in there is to harmonize with wire colors in most of the rest of the world.  It's not really practical to get our hot and neutral colors to agree, but if you get *safety ground* right, that eliminates the biggest hazards.

Needless to say, yellow/green *does not* go to yellow.

Yellow is a hot wire; I couldn't tell you which one.  Obviously blue is the other one.  There's no standard for *which* color is which hot.  Normally, "trying random stuff" is very dangerous, but as long as you're handling grounds and neutrals correctly, swapping around hots is usually pretty safe.

### Where's my ground wire then?

You don't have one. You have metal conduit and metal boxes. That continuous metal shell *is the safety ground*.

Switches pick up ground via their metal yokes... certain receptacles can too.

If the switch's approved instructions absolutely require connecting the ground *as a wire* (i.e. if it can't just pick it up off the yoke), then look in the back of the metal box for a hole slightly smaller than the others.  That will be tapped 10-32 for a "10-32 fine-thread machine screw" aka a small bolt.  Any hardware store will sell those.  They even make green ones!

### Don't install unsafe gear

We all take the safety of electrical equipment for granted, but that doesn't happen by magic.  In the US, an organization called Underwriter's Laboratories (UL) writes the safety standards, the UL White Book, for anything legal to sell in the USA.  CSA does the same with Canada.  This covers stuff like not electrocuting you, not starting a fire, being made of the correct borated plastics that won't accelerate a fire or emit poison smoke.

Device makers *are supposed to* get an independent testing lab (UL, or competitors CSA or ETL) to inspect their designs *and documentation*, torture test the components (e.g. flame test), and then inspect factory production to make sure quality doesn't slide.   But that costs money!

Chinese makers (and a few American ones!) *don't even try* to comply with those minimum standards.  They CAN'T sell the stuff in retail channels, because the retailers will get nicked by the safety agencies (CPSC, FTC etc.)

But direct mail is impossible to patrol because of sheer volume. And somehow, Amazon's warehouses also "get a pass" (good lawyers?) So, direct mail, particularly Amazon Marketplace, has become a superhighway for dangerous imported crud that is $3 cheaper but will burn your house down.

I note that the UL White Book requires a green wire for ground, not yellow/green.  I have a feeling if you look closely at your smart switch,  you will find the usual *fake* marks (CE, CCC, FCC and RoHS) but no legitimate mark.

In that case, send it back and get a real one from a competent retailer.